# Turning a bitfield into a uint8_t

Tags: c, struct, casting, bit-fields, uint8t

My bitfield below represents the 7 status flags for the 6502 CPU. I am trying to emulate the instruction `php`, which pushes a copy of the status flags onto the stack.

```
struct Flags {
    uint8_t C: 1;
    uint8_t Z: 1;
    uint8_t I: 1;
    uint8_t D: 1;
    uint8_t V: 1;
    uint8_t N: 1;
    uint8_t B: 2;
};
```

I need a way to pack each field into a single-byte datatype like `uint8_t` so that I can push it to the stack. However, the code below gives this error: `operand of type 'struct Flags' where arithmetic or pointer type is required`. How do I resolve this problem?

```
int main() {
    struct Flags f = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
    uint8_t f_as_byte = (uint8_t) f;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with bitfields is that it is *implementation-defined* in what order the bits are laid out. This could be rather unacceptable for a 6502 emulator. The `PHP` command must push the status word in the **exact** desired format, i.e. something like

```
uint8_t as_state = f.N << 7 | f.V << 6 | f.B << 4 | f.D << 3 | f.I << 2 | f.Z << 1 | f.C;
```

Your layout is wrong, the `B` member is in wrong position. All in all considering the complex code like one above, maybe it would be easier to just consider the flags as a single `uint8_t` and have access macros for it, something like

```
#define FLAG_N 0x80U
...
#define FLAG_C 0x1U

#define SET_FLAG(flag_var, flag) ((flag_var) |= (flag))
#define CLR_FLAG(flag_var, flag) ((flag_var) &= ~(flag))
#define GET_FLAG(flag_var, flag) ((_Bool)((flag_var) & (flag)))

uint8_t flags = 0;
SET_FLAG(flags, FLAG_C);

if (GET_FLAG(flags, FLAG_N)) { ... }
```

That way the `PHP` instruction can be coded to just push `flags` as is...

[Except that the `B` flag that is pushed is not a flag from the status register...](http://visual6502.org/wiki/index.php?title=6502_BRK_and_B_bit#the_B_flag_and_the_various_mechanisms)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica fixed :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a `union`:

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

struct Flags {
    uint8_t C:1;
    uint8_t Z:1;
    uint8_t I:1;
    uint8_t D:1;
    uint8_t V:1;
    uint8_t N:1;
    uint8_t B:2;
};

union uFlags {
    uint8_t B;
    struct Flags F;
};

int
main()
{
    struct Flags f = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 };
    union uFlags u;

    u.F = f;
    uint8_t f_as_byte = u.B;
}
```

---

With a designated initializer, you may be able to initialize the `union` directly without a separate `f`:

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

struct Flags {
    uint8_t C:1;
    uint8_t Z:1;
    uint8_t I:1;
    uint8_t D:1;
    uint8_t V:1;
    uint8_t N:1;
    uint8_t B:2;
};

union uFlags {
    uint8_t B;
    struct Flags F;
};

int
main()
{
    union uFlags u = {
        .F = { .V = 1 }
    };

    uint8_t f_as_byte = u.B;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of casting the structure as a `(uint8_t)`, you should take its address and cast that as a `(uint8_t *)`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Flags {
    uint8_t C: 1;
    uint8_t Z: 1;
    uint8_t I: 1;
    uint8_t D: 1;
    uint8_t V: 1;
    uint8_t N: 1;
    uint8_t B: 2;
};

int main() {
    struct Flags f = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
    uint8_t f_as_byte = *(uint8_t *)&f;
    printf("flags: %.2X\n", f_as_byte);
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that the actual bit values used to represent the bit-field members are implementation defined. The C Standard does not even guarantee that the `Flags` structure fit in a single byte. This make bit-fields a risky choice to represent hardware registers or instruction opcodes as a would make the emulator non-portable. Little-endian and big-endian systems typically use a different layout for bit-fields members.